# How to do search and replace in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

An obvious way to handle String search and replace is

```
String s = "This will go over well!";
s = s.replace("go", "not go");
```

I wonder .. can the same be done using regex package? Are there benefits from using it?

Can something along the lines of `s/go/not go/g` exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder .. can the same be done using regex package? Are there benefits from using it?

Please look at using `String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` instead of `String#replace(...)` since this uses a regular expression for the first parameter. The [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will tell you more about this. This does give some added flexibility and power but with the price (I believe -- I have not profiled this) of slower execution time.

> Can something along the lines of s/go/not go/g exist?

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Can you please clarify this a bit?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your answer is perfect. Will accept in 5..4 min